# How to initialize a class that manages a buffer whose data type is passed at instantiation.

Tags: c++, variable-types

I need to create a Buffer class whose type of variables that constitute the managed buffer is decided at istantiation time. Thus, I need a buffer class of long int bytes, 30 elements long, I will instantiate something like:

GeneralBuffer myLongBuffer(long int, 30); or GeneralBuffer myLongBuffer(LONG, 30);

While if I need a unsigend floating type:

GeneralBuffer myFloatingBuffer(unsigend float, 30); or or GeneralBuffer myLongBuffer(UFLOATING, 30);

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only if type is known at compile time, google "c++ templates"

Comment: both `std::vector` and `std::array` (C++11) will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since types are a compile-time construct, you can't pass them as arguments to a function. Instead you want templates. Templates allow to instantiate different implementations of a class or function depending on the template type parameters you pass to it. So if you have:

```
template <typename T>
class GeneralBuffer
{
  private:
    T* internal_buffer;
  public:
    GeneralBuffer(size_t size);
};
```

You can instantiate `GeneralBuffer` for `int` and create an object of that type like so:

```
GeneralBuffer<int> my_int_buffer(30);
```

However, this just looks like a reimplementation of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Alternatively, if the size of the buffer is also a compile-time constant, you could also pass it as a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class GeneralBuffer
{
  private:
    T internal_array[N];
  public:
    GeneralBuffer();
};
```

Which you would use like so:

```
GeneralBuffer<int, 30> my_int_buffer;
```

However, this just looks like a reimplementation of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: thank you for suggestions. In your first example, is it necessary to decleare something more in the constructor method to reserve the correct 30 elements space to the internal_buffer array/pointer?

Comment: @fede72bari Yes, you will need to allocate the buffer. At the moment, the class contains only a pointer to `T`.